# <Solved in Unity> C# Render gcode lines from points in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d, render

I've made an algorithm which gets all the points which the extruder in the 3D printer follows. The algorithm saves all the points into a text file like so:

```
[x;y;z]

163.78;53.01;0.25
161.086;50.315;0.25
161.364;50.33;0.25
161.726;50.393;0.25
163.933;52.6;0.25
163.696;51.801;0.25
162.299;50.404;0.25
163.696;51.801;0.25
97.981;136.924;0.55
94.778;137.313;0.55
94.544;136.288;0.55
94.468;136.115;0.55
94.373;135.978;0.55
```

There are hundreds of thousands of these points each gcode file. How do I render them in 3D in a windows form?

I'd like it to look similar to Repetier's visualization or something like this(not the animation, just the lines): http://jherrm.com/gcode-viewer/

I heard it's possible to do with XNA which i have no experience with what so ever.

**EDIT:**
**I decided to make this in Unity 3D using LineRenderers. [can't delete this post]**

Comment: I would suggest rather go for WPF 3D drawing

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the math behind it :D

Comment: This should be in two questions - 1) how to process gcode to give a visualizable structure, 2) how to render 3D in XNA. As a hint - note that your points are organized into groups with the same Z-value; these are the successive layers that the extruder builds up. Each layer forms a closed polygon, and you need to triangulate successive layers.

Comment: I might as well remove this post since i decided to do it in Unity and since I've been playing around with LineRenderer in Unity the whole day and the result is quite nice actually..
https://s2.postimg.org/sxjcdacd5/image.png ||| https://s2.postimg.org/r70bbsuu1/image.png

Answer (score 1):

I would start from this open-source project: [CNC Graphical Backplotter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17424/CNC-Graphical-Backplotter).

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but I've already finished it.. decided to make this in Unity 3D instead..